# Gradle not syncing at all?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I just updated AS since a while and Gradle seems to be broken.

- Create a empty LibGDX gradle project with the latest LibGDX setup.
- Add dependency to core in `build.gradle`. Nothing happens, used to get a popup with something like "Sync now" I believe.
- Clean project does not seem to do anything. Bottom left says nothing about a recent (un)successful clean.
- Rebuild project does not seem to do anything.
- Adding jibberish `sdfdfsdfsffsd;;;sfes;efs` to the gradle file does not change anything. My program still runs, no errors in `build.gradle` and clean still does not do anything.

Never really had problems with AS and Gradle, it just worked out of the box. Now it seems to be broken but I cannot seem to find anything on the subject. A reinstall might fix things but fixing it without a reinstall would be nice.

**Edit**

I somehow managed to trigger the gradle sync by closing/opening AS and opening my project again. But now it won't even recognize the LibGDX framework anymore.

**Edit**

Somehow it seems related with unchecking Android in the LibGDX setup tool. This was no problem in the past for me but once I tried to create a project with the android module enabled it seems to work. My guess is the LibGDX tool messes up somewhere with generating the gradle files but it's still very strange behavior. Perhaps someone could attempt to start a project without the android module and tell me if he is running into the same issues. Note that at first import the default LibGDX program runs fine but importing dependencies through Gradle and restarting AS is causing issues here.

Comment: Have you tried "Invalidate Caches / Restart" option from the File menu?

Comment: @SnehPandya Then I get `The modules below are not imported from Gradle anymore, check to remove from project` Core & Desktop (I only checked desktop in setup)

Comment: Probably its the issue with Core as it was existing as an older project and Android Studio is not able to recognize LibGDX because of the older imports and configurations.

Comment: Check Core and Desktop both and see if it works.

Comment: @SnehPandya It just removes the modules from the project. Anyway, I created another project. Only difference is that I added Android core this time. Might be that or the `Invalidate caches` but it seemed to fix itself. Now Gradle immediately asks for a sync on a change and it actually loads my added dependencies.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: @SnehPandya Well somehow I ran into issues again. Started up another project but gradle import has vanished in AS. So I picked regular import, selected gradle and it started making core(main) & core(test). Rebooted and these vanished again but now gradle has the same issues again. I am currently reinstalling AS.

Comment: @SnehPandya After a reinstall I get the same. On the first import I can get the desktop module to run. Still, gradle changes seem to get unnoticed. When I restart AS and open the project I lose LibGDX dependancy somehow. Really strange, was planning to do some work but this is keeping me going in circles for a couple hours now.

Comment: @cricket_007 Why change Android Studio tag to Android? I am talking about AS IDE here....

Comment: I do not have any experience with LibGDX, I would suggest you to check this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle and this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Project-Setup-Gradle

Comment: @SnehPandya Yeah, I have been running AS with LibGDX for years. And it worked fine without a Android module. Something messed this up I guess so for now I just keep the android module. Thanks for trying!